# transform array with map and reduce

Tags: javascript

I have several arrays like that I'm getting from a web service:

```
const a = [ { label: 'A', value: 100 }, { label: 'B', value: 200 } ];
const b = [ { label: 'A', value: 50 }, { label: 'B', value: 300 } ];
const c = [ { label: 'A', value: 20 }, { label: 'B', value: 130 } ];
const d = [ { label: 'A', value: 10 }, { label: 'B', value: 25 } ];
```

and I would like to have something like that (in a React state):

```
[ 
    { label: 'A', a: 100, b: 50, c: 20, d: 10 }, 
    { label: 'B', a: 200, b: 300, c: 130, d: 25 } 
]
```

using modern JavaScript, I guess with `map` and `reduce`

**EDIT:**

I was not clear at all at first. I want to update my state when I get new data.

if my current state is:

```
[ 
    { label: 'A', a: 100, b: 50, c: 20, d: 10 }, 
    { label: 'B', a: 200, b: 300, c: 130, d: 25 } 
]
```

and I'm getting

```
{ title: "a", values: [ { label: 'A', value: 12 }, { label: 'B', value: 13 } ] };
```

I want to update my state to

```
[ 
    { label: 'A', a: 12, b: 50, c: 20, d: 10 }, 
    { label: 'B', a: 13, b: 300, c: 130, d: 25 } 
]
```

my best attempts was:

```
myFunction().then(data => {
  const {chartData} = this.state;
  chartData[data.title] = Object.keys(data.values).map(key => ({
    label: chartData[data.title] || data.values[key].label,
    [data.title]: data.values[key].value,
    ...chartData[data.title]
  });
  this.setState({chartData});
})
```

Comment: That's a good guess. Have you tried anything yet? What went wrong with your best attempt (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: Try first...ask when you run into trouble

Comment: @charlietfl of course I tried before posting but I don't really want to share my tries =)

Comment: *"don't want to share tries"* ... But that's expected here. The objective is to help you fix your code attempts, not to be a free code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, I guess I was just ashamed by my bad attempts. I'm not considering stack as a free code writing service at all.

Comment: Showing any attempt will get you a lot more sympathetic help than no attempt and cut down the down/close votes. Also allows you to learn better where you might be going off track or what you tried had a simple mistake in it

Comment: yes I'm editing my post.

Comment: FYI - the few questions I have asked here were due to dumb mistakes in the code I showed or my research and got down voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the given `state` array, look for an item with the wanted `label` and update the properties.

```js
function update(state, { title, values }) {
    return values.reduce((r, { label, value }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => o.label === label);

        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { label });
        Object.assign(temp, { [title]: value });
        return r;
    }, state);
}

var state = [{ label: 'A', a: 100, b: 50, c: 20, d: 10 }, { label: 'B', a: 200, b: 300, c: 130, d: 25 }],
    data = { title: "a", values: [{ label: 'A', value: 12 }, { label: 'B', value: 13 }] };

update(state, data);

console.log(state);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const glue = (label, ...vars) => ([].concat(vars).filter(i => i.label === label).reduce((agg, i) => ({ ...agg, ...i }), {}));
```

where

```
glue('A', [a,b,c,d]);
glue('B', [a,b,c,d]);
// .. and so on
`
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why,  to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Answer (score 1):

Here idea is

- Combine all the values in one array
- Use a array to keep alphabets
- Loop over combined array and for each element in combined array add vales to labels and alphabet based as per index of combined array

```js
const a = [{ label: 'A', value: 100 }, { label: 'B', value: 200 }];
const b = [{ label: 'A', value: 50 }, { label: 'B', value: 300 }];
const c = [{ label: 'A', value: 20 }, { label: 'B', value: 130 }];
const d = [{ label: 'A', value: 10 }, { label: 'B', value: 25 }];

let alpha = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
let combine = [a,b,c,d]

let op = combine.reduce((op,inp,i) => {
  inp.forEach(({label,value}) => {
    op[label] = op[label] || {label}
    op[label][alpha[i]] = value
  })  
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with all the arrays using [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) (The key names are required to create the properties in the output. You could add more arrays to this object). Then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the entries returned by [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const a = [ { label: 'A', value: 100 }, { label: 'B', value: 200 } ];
const b = [ { label: 'A', value: 50 }, { label: 'B', value: 300 } ];
const c = [ { label: 'A', value: 20 }, { label: 'B', value: 130 } ];
const d = [ { label: 'A', value: 10 }, { label: 'B', value: 25 } ];

const input = { a, b, c, d };

const merged = Object.entries(input).reduce((r, [key, arr]) => {
  arr.forEach(({label, value}) => {
    r[label] = r[label] || { label };
    r[label][key] = value;
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```